# Arrays in Objective-C main method. Sigserve errors. Newb

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, memory, segmentation-fault

In Objective-C how should I best approximate what in Java I am doing like this:

```
static private String[] array {"A", "B", "C"};
```

What I think I need is a simple array that I can index into with some integers. Alternative suggestions are welcome but bear in mind that if I am getting stuck on this then I am pretty much hopeless anyway.

As a test, I have tried using

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C"];
```

in the main method but any more than one array of this type and I get Sig 11 or 10 errors. This happens even if I just have the arrays followed by NSLog statements. Just one array only.

Is it the case that this type of array is just unworkable in the main method? I really don't understand why it causes errors when I add a second array. They aren't even large.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters to [initWithObjects](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithObjects:) need to end in `nil`, like so:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
```

Comment: This is mentioned quite explicitly in the documentation for the method, by the way. It's always good to check the docs for a method you're using, especially if it doesn't seem to be working right.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just got into iPhone development and also had a lot of issues with initWithObjects.  Now I know why.  I didn't put the nil.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. This has solved my problem and will teach me to check the documentation more thoroughly next time. Thanks.